# How can I stop Firefox's autocomplete from overriding jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, autocomplete

I am losing my mind over this.

I have an extremely simple form that uses jQuery autocomplete to query my database, and return a list of store/customer names as the user types. It looks like this:

```
<form action="/" name="myForm" id="myForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="my_autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have 'autocomplete="off" set on both the form and the input field. However, after selecting anything and submitting the form, Firefox refuses to stop autofilling the field, overriding the jQuery autocomplete and rendering some values un-selectable:

[image: like this]

I have been Googling and I can't seem to find anyone else having this issue.

What am I doing wrong? Could it be a Firefox bug in v51?

---

Update to add: Apparently, this is actually happening for *all* input fields that utilize autocomplete, not just my own application, including sites like Apple and Amazon:

[image: Amazon]

This is happening both on Firefox 51 on Mac, and Firefox 38 on Linux, which I find extremely odd, given that I've been on v38 for quite some time and never remember this happening until the last few weeks. I'm so stumped.

Comment: did you try `<input autocomplete='nope' />` as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: Yes, I even tried that too. :(

Comment: I have never had this issue and work primarily in FF for all my development.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style="display:none"` to your input.

But, i suggest try reinstalling your firefox because the auto complete also appear on other website like amazon which is not normal. Also try reseting your firefox to factory setting
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems

Comment: Thanks, a brand-new profile was what I ended up doing, since I could never track down the problem. I chalked it up to some obscure config option, or maybe an addon that tried to auto-update at some point and got screwed up.. who knows.